# Everything works besides the turning the visibity from 'startButtonGame' back to visible

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing a blackjack game. everything has been working so far besides for this little detail. Basically the start game button should only be visible before a game and after a game. I have no problem with making the visibility hidden but it does not work the other way around when I finish a game.

```
function startGame() {
    startGameButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
    if (!player.playerName) {
        player.playerName = prompt("What's your name?")
        player.chips = 100

        playerEl.textContent = "Player: " + player.playerName;
    }

    if (cards.length < 2) {
        let bet = prompt('how much do you want to bet (chips: ' + player.chips + ')')
        player.chips = player.chips - bet;
        chipsEl.textContent = "Chips: " + player.chips;
    }

    let firstCard = randomCard();
    let secondCard = randomCard();
    cards = [firstCard, secondCard];
    let tableFirstCard = randomCard();
    let tableSecondCard = randomCard();
    tableCards = [tableFirstCard, tableSecondCard];
    let message = "";
    let hasBlackJack = false;
    let isAlive = true;

    sum = firstCard + secondCard;
    newCardButton.style.visibility = "visible";
    startGameButton.textContent = "New Game";

    if (sum < 21) {
        message = "Do you want to draw a new card?";
    } else if (sum === 21) {
        message = "You've got Blackjack!";
        newCardButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
        startGameButton.style.visibility = "visible";
        player.chips = player.chips + bet * 2
        hasBlackJack = true;
    } else {
        startGameButton.style.visibility = "visible";
        isAlive = false;
        message = "Bad luck! You're out of the game!";
    }

    messageEl.textContent = message;
    cardsEl.textContent = "Cards: " + firstCard + " " + secondCard;
    tableCardsEl.textContent = "Table Cards: " + tableSecondCard + " " + tableSecondCard;
    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + sum;
    console.log("blackjack: " + hasBlackJack);
    console.log("is Alive: " + isAlive);
}
```

I have tried to even switch it around to see if it makes any difference all that happens in:

```
if (sum < 21) {
        message = "Do you want to draw a new card?";
    } else if (sum === 21) {
        message = "You've got Blackjack!";
        newCardButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
        startGameButton.style.visibility = "visible";
        player.chips = player.chips + bet * 2
        hasBlackJack = true;
    } else {
        startGameButton.style.visibility = "visible";
        isAlive = false;
        message = "Bad luck! You're out of the game!";
    }
```

everything in the if statement is happening aside from the visibility part.

if you need more context here is a link to the code: https://github.com/pedrosilva410/blackjack-game

Comment: _"if you need more context here is a link to the code"_ - a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question. (Code only shown via external platforms might change or disappear over time, which would leave the question without proper context for future readers.)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the whole code on your Github, the problem is that your `startGame` function is only called when you just started the game (which makes sense, obviously). It does nothing during the game.

Your instructions to make the "Start game" button visible are correct, you just put them in the wrong place. Add them to your `drawCard` function as well.

```js
function drawCard() {

    if (hasBlackJack == false || isAlive == true) {
        let newCard = randomCard();
        let newTableCard = randomCard();
        sum = sum + newCard

        if (sum < 21) {
            message = "Do you want to draw a new card?";
        } else if (sum === 21) {
            message = "You've got Blackjack!";
            newCardButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
            startGameButton.style.visibility = "visible";
            hasBlackJack = true;
        } else {
            isAlive = false;
            message = "Bad luck! You're out of the game!";
            startGameButton.style.visibility = "visible";
            newCardButton.style.visibility = "hidden"
        }

        messageEl.textContent = message;
        cardsEl.textContent = cardsEl.textContent + " " + newCard;
        tableCardsEl.textContent = tableCardsEl.textContent + " " + newTableCard;
        sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + sum;
        console.log("blackjack: " + hasBlackJack);
        console.log("is Alive: " + isAlive);
    }
}
```